# EF 6 SaveChanges with Transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following issue when trying to save a brand new object tree.

I have Created an object with a number of child objects. The child objects are all 1 level deep from the initial object created. My problem is that one of the child objects that I am attempting to create also has a FK into one of the other child objects. So on the initial creation of these objects the FK's are of course 0 because the child object that hasn't yet been created has it's PK currently at 0. When I call SaveChanges on the context it errors because the key's are indeterminate on the child object that is reliant on the existence of the other child object. This is quite a large object tree and so it seems I will need to save the parent first and then other objects in order so that I can obtain the new PK value to use against those tables that are reliant on others. The trouble is I want an all or nothing situation, so I want all objects to save or none. SaveChanges in EF 6 removed the ability to pass false as a parameter and then call SaveAllChanges(). What's the best approach for me now to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use transaction. In transaction, you should first add parent object to dbset and use `Context.SaveChanges()` the entity will not be created on db until you commit the transaction. However it will reserve id(primary key). So you can use this id on child objects. You can do the same thing for child objects, if you need id(primary key) use `Context.SaveChanges()`.

```
using (var myTransaction = Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                       //Crate Parent Object
                       Context.SaveChanges();
                       //Create Child Object;
                           Context.SaveChanges();
                           //Other Childs
                             Context.SaveChanges();
                             //If everything goes well
                             myTransaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        myTransaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I am using a repository type pattern. So I cant easily wrap this in a 'using' statement. I'm guessing I'd need to expose the BeginTransaction in another method along with the commit and rollback.

Comment: You can use Transaction Scope also.

Comment: If you're using a repository pattern have a look at injecting a "unit of work" which is basically a wrapper around the transaction functionality - exposing commit and rollback (and possibly create transaction)

Comment: Having to save the parent to obtain the PK is code smells. I encourage you to review your model/mappings.

Comment: Parent => tableA, ChildTableB has FK to TableA, ChildTableC has FK to TableA and FK to ChildTableB, so ChildTableB needs to be saved before ChildTableC. If I try to do saveChanges on single object TableA FK's in TableC for TableB are 0 and EF cannot Resolve. So I need to Save Parent with ChildB. then obtain PK of TableB Assign to TableC and then save again.

Comment: I dislike this approach. For cases like this you could configure DatabaseGeneratedOption for PKs. It indicates EF to retrieve generated PKs values after parent inserts and update child objects accordingly before submitting them : modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .Property(m => m.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);